# Assign only object value from csv to a variable

Tags: powershell

With some help I was able to import the .CSV file and read the first and last row elements, but I want to assign only the batch id to a variable, but when I include it in a email body, I get the whole object rather than value.

```
    $getBatchIds=(Import-csv $file.FullName)
    $firstElement= $getBatchIds | Select-Object -First 1 batch_id
    $lastElement= $getBatchIds | Select-Object -Last 1  batch_id
```

`$getBatchIds` to import the file

`$firstElement $lastElement` to get the last row elements

This is the object that is included in the email body, that assigns them to individual variables and I output them in the email body

```
1       12-06-2019 07:54:47 @{Batch_Id=2129475} @{Batch_Id=2138701}

2       11-06-2019 09:40:41 @{Batch_Id=2103516} @{Batch_Id=2129456}
```

Comment: what is the question? i don't understand your post ... [*blush*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-ExpandProperty`:

```
$getBatchIds  = Import-Csv -Path $file.FullName
$firstElement = $getBatchIds | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty "batch_id"
$lastElement  = $getBatchIds | Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty "batch_id"
```